# Manage events in Spring app

Tags: spring, events, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC app that needs to send email notification each time and event occur. Those events are detected in three different classes so I need my email service to watch for them. How can I control if an event have occurred? I was thinking in use an observer pattern but I'm not sure if this is a good idea and I don't know how to know what event I'm processing.

Comment: I think that good solution is to use Spring AOP http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/aop_with_spring.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess whether using an observer is a good idea depends on your application architecture and your design preferences. If you do choose to go with the event approach, Spring provides infrastructure to support that.

In order to implement the event approach with Spring you will need a publish, a listener and an event definition. You will achieve that with classes that implement `ApplicationEventPublisherAware`, `ApplicationListener` and `ApplicationEvent`

You can find a detailed explanation at http://techighost.com/event-handling-with-spring-framework/